# Can I change how gedit prints its page header?

Tags: linux, printing, gedit

I'm often using `gedit` to print text documents. One thing I don't like is that it prints the full path to the document inside the page header, which sometimes overlaps what's in the top right corner; I'd like it to print the file name only.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for this is

```
  return g_file_get_parse_name (location);
```

in a function

```
  gedit_document_get_uri_for_display:
```

that would need to be changed and gedit rebuilt or a PR created.

Answer (score 0):

No. This seems to be hardcoded in the source code [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/2b1ce4cb157e154fcc6853e00b5887cf7789372c/gedit/gedit-document.c#L1090).
You can, however, omit the entire page header by deselecting the checkbox *Print page headers* in the tab *Text Editor* under section *Page header* of the printing dialogue.

Comment: I'm torn. I'd like to accept both answers because they fit different valid contexts for my question, only one of which I had considered, aka the user standpoint to which there's only configuration files to change applications behaviour. @chris-hill gives a perfectly valid answer for a developer or more-advanced-user. Would you guys mind merging your answers?

Comment: Chris Hill copied the content from the link to the source code I provided and explained the usual procedure of a feature request in FLOSS development. If this anwers your question, go ahead and accept it. I don't mind.

Comment: Call it a deal :-) .